# Is anybody able to recommend a GNU/Linux alternative to RegexRx?

Tags: linux, regex

On the Mac I use at work, [RegexRX](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/regexrx/id498370702?mt=12) is installed. Unfortunately, It only runs on OS X and I'm looking for a GNU/Linux alternative, preferably a FLOSS one.

The key functionality that I require is:

1. Given a regex, show what text does/doesn't match the pattern
2. Provide a way to export the pattern as a search pattern in a number of languages (mainly PHP and Python).

I've already looked at alternativeto.net and tried [Regexp Testing Tool](http://sourceforge.net/projects/regexper/) to no effect.

Answer (score 4):

I've found [RegExr](http://regexr.com/) very easy to use; it's an online tool that lets you build a regular expression as well as how it matches a sample text.

[image: RegExr screenshot]

Pros:

- Edit regex and see matches live
- Online (runs anywhere with a browser)
- FLOSS ([MIT license](https://github.com/gskinner/regexr/blob/master/LICENSE))
- Explains the meaning of various characters in the expression when cursor hovers over them
- Includes a cheat sheet and reference for the occasion when you forget exactly what something does

Cons:

- Export expression/pattern available but not specifically for Python/PHP (although I'm not sure how much that matters, given how trivial it is to write code once the pattern is given)

Comment: Thanks. I'll put it through its paces and see what I can see. If I get the results I want, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use the Google Chrome Regular Expression Checker tool from the Chrome Extensions.

It is free and a compliant regexp will work in both PHP and python by simple copy and paste.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I can't seem to find it in Chrome's Web store. Could you please provide a link?